# Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.saveApp(...).then is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

```
// Component code
this.props.saveApp(values, data).then((result) => {
          //do something

}).catch((error) => {

});
```

I'm using react redux

below is my action

https://pastebin.com/embed_js/EA98HRpj

Comment: can you please post the whole component code?

Comment: `return disptch => `
Typo there, if you've copied your original code.

Besides this, make sure that you've actually connected action to `connect()` and that you've imported it correctly.

Comment: @ Christos Dimitroulas
whole component code
https://pastebin.com/embed_js/YaRaQiB3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the promise in your action and also the response is not returned in the correct place. See my comments to understand what I edited:

```js
export function saveApp(appvalue, fdata) {

    return dispatch => {

        return request // You need to add the return here!!
          .post(\'http://appplay.net:8082/api/v1/addFile\')
          .send(fdata)
          .then(function(res) {
            // res.body, res.headers, res.status
            console.log(res.body.data);
            var downloadurl = res.body.data;
            // console.log(values);
            // this.saveApp( values, downloadurl );
            var platfrom1 = (appvalue.Platform === "iOS")? "2" : "1";
            var ref_newapp = db.ref().child("Apps");
            var auto_id = ref_newapp.push();
            auto_id.set({
                "App_Icon": appvalue.appicon,
                "App_Name": appvalue.appname,
                "Download_URL": downloadurl,
                "Is_Active": parseInt(appvalue.radiostatus, 10),
                "Platform": parseInt(platfrom1, 10),
                "Version" :appvalue.version
            });

            return res; // I think you want to return the res here!!
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            // err.message, err.response
          });
    }
}
```